# Restkit JSON error parsing dates in range 1969/12/07 to 1970/01/25 GMT

Tags: json, parsing, ios7, restkit, ios8

Running Restkit 0.23 and iOS7.1.2 and iOS8gms when dates in range 1969/12/08 to 1970/01/25 GMT are encountered the parsing to JSON fails with an error: [datasource.table.values.property]: Parsing date N was not recognized as a date format... where N is a number of seconds.
I am unable to determine the JSON parser that is in use. 
Restkit documentation refers to either YAJL or SBJSON being pluggable. 
If someone can advise how to identify the parser in use and to change to another parser that would be much appreciated. Otherwise if anyone can advise an alternative resolution that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the backend which is using FlexJSON and is a known feature of FlexJSON:
(http://sourceforge.net/p/flexjson/discussion/686321/thread/029d17be/). 
Trying to use JSONDeserializer but Flexjson is having issues parsing the Unix TimeStamps into Date objects, only if the date is in the range of Dec. 7th, 1969 to Jan. 25th, 1970.  All other dates outside of that range are parsed fine.  The error that it's giving is: [JSONException: : Parsing date 21600000 was not recognized as a date format]

So no problem at all with the iOS native JSON parser which is what RestKit is using, RestKit is simply faithfully passing back the server error messages.